# How do I alter a message in the message queue independent of site language?

Tags: status-messages

I want to programatically alter a message in the message queue. The message I want to alter is set in the message queue by `function comment_form_submit()` in `comment.module`, i.e.:

```
if ($comment->status == COMMENT_NOT_PUBLISHED) {
  if (!user_access('administer comments')) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Your comment has been queued for review by site administrators and will be published after approval.'));
  }
}
```

Instead of this, I want the call to `drupal_set_message()` to be this:

```
drupal_set_message(t('Your comment will be published when you validate your e-mail address.'));
```

How do I do this?

**Postscript:** Based on the answer below by Topsitemakers, I got this working for any language by using `array_search()` inside a custom `MYMODULE_comment_submit` to search the message array, and then compare the *translated* strings to identify the key of the string to alter.

This is the working code I ended up with:

```
$mm = drupal_get_messages('status', TRUE);
$key = array_search(t('Your comment has been queued for review by site administrators and will be published after approval.'), $mm['status']);
if (FALSE !== $key) {
  $mm['status'][$key] = t('Your comment will be published when you validate your e-mail address.');
}
foreach ($mm['status'] as $msg) {
  drupal_set_message($msg, 'status');
}
```

Comment: Could you post here the code used for comparing the messages ("sniffing")? I think you should be able to compare the messages using `t()` function which will make sure the text will match no matter the language.

Comment: 5 more edits and question will get wikified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare messages using the `t()` function, as it will localize both messages and compare them.
Just use the original text in English you want to find and wrap it in `t()` function. E.g.:

```
if ($message == t('This is a sample message')) {
  // Alter the message/perform additional processing.
}
```